# is there any ways to automatically trigger ink smart contract based on certain conditions?

Tags: ink, smart-contract

How to auto-execute smart contract based on certain conditions ?

For example:

The contract period has exceeded the deadline -> auto-execute `pay` without interfering from user

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to automate smart contract functions solely from within a smart contract.

The smart contract requires a transaction that supplies it with gas (CPU Time / Storage fees), which allows it to perform operations. Without the gas, the smart contract is just a set of instructions on-chain.

You need to create an external service that calls your contract at set periods. The call should execute `pay` if the deadline is passed.

There may be [Oracle services](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43740/how-to-automatically-schedule-the-execution-of-a-function-in-the-future) that do this for you but I don't know of any.

Comment: I know it is possible for use oracle to control the automation transaction (ex: Chainlink Automation in evm-compatible ). Do we have any oracle providers support ink! smart contract ?

Comment: Potentially [Kylin](https://www.kylin.network/) as they have contracts written in ink! and they are developing an oracle service. Seems they are live on Rococo and Kusama